# Need Objective Modbus Java Library help

Tags: java, modbus

Does anybody know is there any Objective Modbus Java library ( Modbus + ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [JaMod](http://jamod.sourceforge.net/)?

> This project represents a Modbus implementation in 100% Java. It can be used to implement Modbus masters and slaves in various flavors:
>
> - Serial
>     ASCII, RTU (Master only), BIN
> - IP
>     TCP, UDP